# how to not show icon in android action bar list view control

Tags: android

I am using a list view control in the action bar to navigate my top level views.

Similar to google maps app.

When I click on the list view spinner title (also acting as page title) then my options are displayed - each option has an icon on the left.

When I select an option from the list view I need to show that option in the title but without the icon on the left. Only the text.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custom `Adapter` where you override `getView()` and `getDropDownView()`. In `getDropDownView()` you inflate a layout with an icon and in `getView()` you inflate a layout without an icon.